# Is it legal to decrement arguments within a function?

Tags: recursion, arguments

Is it legal to decrement arguments within a function?

```
int Test(int num){
  if(num == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d,", num);
    Test (num--);  //-- Is this statement is legal ?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid example for a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Note, that every call to `Test` will have it's "own" `num` though, they do not share the same `num`. That's why this is actually the same:

```
int Test(int num){
  if(num == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("%d,", no);
    Test (num - 1);  // Simply subtract one here
  }
}
```

Also you will end up with an infinite loop when calling this with a number < 0:

```
Test(-1) // This loops forever
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using (num-1);

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming this is java code?)

It's perfectly legal, but note that it doesn't effect the variable outside of the function- `num` is copied-by-value into the function, so you are only editing a copy. Each time you call `Test` it gets a new copy of the current value of `num` from where it was called. So for example with this code:

```
int num = 2;
printf("Num before Test : %d,", num);
int res = Test(num);
printf("Result : %d,", res);
printf("Num after Test : %d,", num);

int Test(int num){
    if(num == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("In Test : %d,", num);
        Test (num--); 
    }
}
```

The output would be :

```
Num before Test : 2
In Test : 2
In Test : 1
Result : 0
Num after Test : 2
```

Note that while `res` is probably the result you want, `num` isn't changed.

Comment: yes, above code ended up printing same number infinite times and caused stack overflow.

Comment: @sasha ah, I missed that - `num++` is 'post-increment', which means `num` gets increased _after_ it is used. So Test is called again with the current value of `num`, and _then_ `num` is incremented, which is useless because it's out of scope. So the result is that yes, Test just keeps getting called with the same value of `num` and crashes. Using `num-1` like the other answer said works. Sorry about that, I should have realised my error.